# How to recover a files which are encrypted by ransomware

Tags: apache, xampp, remote-desktop, virus, static-ip-address

As I'm using a windows 7.We are configured public ip to access our apache server. After a Remote desktop connection via **Anydesk** Ended. All the Files in System are encrypted with **.deep** extension. Every Folder Contains Text files that has id and **mrdeep@protonmail.com** and bitcoin donate information and also system already has K7 **AntiSecurity**(Licensed but about to end).But after affected, K7 automatically vanished. Hence can anyone help me to  recover those files and also guide me to escape from such viruses in future..

Comment: Best to just restore from backup. Or is this the event you were waiting for to start doing daily backups, if so do not ignore it, start now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it looks that this is Scarab ransomware new version. Scarab has decryption tool developed by Dr. Web. You should try that, it may work for this .deep extension or just use anti-malware tools, clean everything. Then maybe Data Recovery Pro will help with data decryption. Keep your anti-virus and anti-malware up-to-date so you can avoid this nasty virus. These most commonly come from infected spam email attachments. so clean that box more often and scan your system more frequently. Good luck!